# Pylint sublime plugin development

Tags: python, sublimetext2, pylint

Is there a way to force pylint to see `sublime` and `sublime_plugin` modules?
I have tried adding sublime folder to `pythonpath` but it hasn't worked out.

These two errors really annoy me:

- PyLinter:  F0401: Unable to import 'sublime'
- PyLinter:  F0401: Unable to import 'sublime_plugin'

Thanks.

Comment: which pylint plugin are you using?

Comment: sublime plugin PyLinter

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but utmost difficult.

You can try to see if these modules are available as .py files in Sublime Text 2 source code and drop then to PYTHONPATH Pylint reads.

If the modules in the question are native modules, Pylint can see only if they are distributed as shared libraries and you point PYTHONPATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH to this modules. If the modules are embedded inside Sublime Text 2 binary you have little hope to make Pylint understand them (unless you provide hinting by hand). In this case the behavior is operating system specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Windows. I solved this by *duplicating* both `sublime.py` and `sublime_plugin.py`, which are located in

```
C:\applications\text\sublime_text_3\
```

into one of the `PYTHONPATH` directories. I opened up a command prompt and typed `echo %PYTHONPATH%`, which printed

```
c:\applications\programming\python_341\Lib\site-packages\
```

So I placed a copy of both files in that directory. This must be done at any Sublime update, assuming that the py files are also updated.

(These are actually the *only* py files in the Sublime install directory.)